# jQuery: Body background that scrolls sideways?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to animate the body background sideways (maybe changing left parameter) without having to make a DIV that acts like a body element?

What I want: my website's body background is a picture with 3000px width , I want it scroll to the left 1px every second.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').animate({'background-position':'+=3000'}, 3000000, 'linear');
```

Comment: I don't know why, but this solution causes my background image to be height centered.

Comment: If you specify only one value, the other defaults to 50%. You can set the y-position to 0px in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css background-position property.
See this
[background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-position&preval=10px%20200px)

Now You can make a javascript function that updates the positions every 1 second.